# Mongodb query issue using aggregate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am struggling to write this query.

From the following dataset, I want to find out the documents who's resources array have 'EC2' and **print out ONLY that element from the array**.

> **Data**:

```js
[ 
  { 
    "projectName": "first"
    "resources": [
      {
          "resource": "EC2",
          "region": "ap-south-1",
          "params": {
              "ImageId": "ami-0bcf5425cdc1d8a85",
              "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
          }
      },
      {
          "resource": "S3",
          "region": "ap-south-1",
          "params": {
              "Bucket": "test-bucket"
          }
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

> **Expected output**:

```
{
    "resource": "EC2",
    "region": "ap-south-1",
    "params": {
      "ImageId": "ami-0bcf5425cdc1d8a85",
      "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
    }
}
```

The query that I have tried :

```js
const projects = await Project.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          resources: {
            $elemMatch: {
              resource: { $eq: 'EC2' },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          resourceName: '$resources.resource',
          region: '$resources.region' // and so on
        },
      },
    ]);
```

**^^ This is returning other elements from the resources array as well**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @turivishal

I came up with this solution:

```js
const projects = await Project.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          resources: {
            $elemMatch: {
              resource: { $eq: 'EC2' },
            },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          resource: {
            $filter: {
              input: '$resources',
              as: 'each', // use $$ to refer
              cond: { $eq: ['$$each.resource', 'EC2'] },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `resources` array and find matching `resource`
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first matching element from above filtered result
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above return object to root

```
const projects = await Project.aggregate([

  { $match: { resources: { $elemMatch: { resource: { $eq: "EC2" } } } } },
  // or below match is equal to above match condition
  // { $match: { "resources.resource": "EC2" } },

  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$resources",
              cond: { $eq: ["$$this.resource", "EC2"] }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }

])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T1o5ibVnaac)

Comment: Hi, thanks, **filter** worked for me. I used this ```$filter: {
  input: '$resources',
  as: 'each',
  cond: { $eq: ['$$each.resource', 'EC2'] },
   },```

One QUESTION, why did I have to use 2 $$ symbols? I assume first is for the document and second is to refer the `as` that is `each` variable?? CONFUSED

Comment: single `$` is refer to current root document' fields like you can access projectName field in filter using `$projectName`, and `$$` refers $filter's `as` variable name.

Comment: is there a way to select the fields of the matching elements and returning them?

Comment: i am not getting you exactly, can you please explain more, you can check the playground it is exactly same as your expected result.

Comment: I am getting the elements filtered by the filtered operator. What if I want to project specific fields of the filtered elements. Like I want to project only the params property of each filtered element.

Comment: you need to add new stage  `{ $project: { .. add your required fields } }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230864/discussion-between-karan-kumar-and-turivishal).